# jQuery: hover (mouseleave event fired when mouse is over child)

Tags: jquery, hover, parent

I want to create a zoom effect on some thumbs.

Here is my javascript simplified code :

```
parent.hover(
 function(){
   parent.stop().animate({/* css */}, inputZoomDuration, "linear");
   wrapper.stop().animate({/* css */}, inputZoomDuration, "linear");
   child.stop().animate({/* css */}, inputZoomDuration, "linear");
 },
 function(){
  alert("leave");
  child.stop().animate({/* css */}, 140, "linear");
  wrapper.stop().animate({/* css */}, 140, "linear");
  parent.stop().animate({/* css */}, 140, "linear");
 }
);
```

and the html is like :

```
<div parent>
 <div wrapper>
  <div child>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I increase the size of all my divs when I over the "parent". But a soon as I over (or leave, btw) one of the child, the alert appears.
Without the alert, the result is a very bugy animation.
Is there any way to prevent the mouseleave event to be fired when a child is overed?

Best regards,

thanks.

**Edit :**
Here is the greasemonkey script : http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/94786
and a link to test it : http://browse.deviantart.com/
We can see in the console that the mouseleave event is trigerred when I leave the orange div, unlike this example : http://www.jsfiddle.net/wnuS6/3/ where the event is not fired when I leave the red div.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Can you provide actual code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use jquery (1.4.2) in a greasemonkey script.
The code is a bit tricky. I'll try to post it here as soon as I clean it a bit, and test what you say.

Comment: If possible, create a [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/) example that reproduces the issue. (Be sure to choose the correct library on the left.)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I can't reproduce the issue with jsFiddle. I when even tried to create a similar code : http://www.jsfiddle.net/wnuS6/3/
In this example, all works fine. When the mouse is over the red div, the size of all divs is increased. But when I leave the red div (child of the green one), I don't fire the mouseleave event. In my greasemonkey script, when I leave the child div, the event is triggered. I'd like to post the userscript, but you need the greasemonkey extension (for firefox 3.6.x). I know that without examples, it is difficult to understand the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some investigations, it seems that the problem comes from greasemonkey.
Here is what the wiki said :

> Some versions of jQuery will not run
>   inside the Greasemonkey sandbox. As of
>   this writing, 1.3.2 does work, but
>   1.4.1 does not. It is possible to patch 1.4 versions of jQuery to work,
>   see jQuery Forum: Importing jQuery
>   1.4.1 into greasemonkey scripts generates an error

However, all versions 1.4.x patched of jQuery still don't work in my specific hover case AND only with greasemonkey (indeed, I test the same script in jsFiddle, and that works with jQuery 1.4.4).

To solve the problem, I simply use jQuery 1.3.2 (and of course, I have to adapt my code a bit).

Answer (score 2):

Change the event from `.hover()` to `.mouseenter()`. This will ensure that it will remain active until you leave the parent div area, which you can detect using the `mouseleave()` event. http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/ - http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: `hover` with two handlers is a shortcut for `mouseenter/mouseleave`.

Comment: Hover is a shortcut for mouseenter and mouseleave, so changing it won't make a difference. The real problem is with event bubbling.

Comment: @Box9: Regarding bubbling, that's what `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` are supposed to resolve since they're designed to emulate Microsoft's `mouseenter/mouseleave` events, which don't bubble. I think there's something else going on.

Comment: @patrick, you're right, my mistake about the bubbling. Mouseover and mouseout are the ones with bubbling. My answer is invalid then.